# Using two versions of pandas at the same time

Tags: python, pandas, pip

I am trying to run two independent codes (let's call them code 1 and code 2) that use two different versions of pandas (version 0.20.1 for the code 1 and 1.2.4 for code 2). Code 1 doesn't run on version 1.2.4 and code 2 doesn't run on version 0.20.1. I am looking for an efficient way of having the most up to date version of pandas on my computer (1.2.4 in that case) while still being able to run codes (such as code 1) that require older versions of pandas. Ideally, I would like to know if there's a way I can specify the version of pandas that I want to use at the beginning of my script before running it.

One of the solutions that I found online was to use the `pkg_resources` package as follows:

```
import pkg_resources 
pkg_resources.require("pandas==0.20.1")
import pandas as pd
```

but I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-74003f72683b>", line 1, in <module>
    pkg_resources.require("pandas==0.20.1")

  File "C:\Users\**UserName**\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 886, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))

  File "C:\Users\**UserName**\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 777, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)

VersionConflict: (pandas 1.2.4 (c:\users\**UserName**\anaconda3\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('pandas==0.20.1'))
```

If possible, I would like to know if there's a way to do it without changing one of the two codes that I try to run. Thank you!!

Comment: From the paths in the traceback, it looks like you are using conda. You can use [conda environments](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-environments) to have multiple versions of python and packages.

Comment: I will definitely look into this. I was looking for a solution where I would just need to specify the version of pandas that I want to run at the beginning of the script because other people with other versions of pandas might also run those two codes. By creating a conda environment, every other user of the codes will also have to create conda environments on their computers, right?

Comment: you have virtual enviroment (`venv`) to run different versions. And when it activate `venv` then you can install `pip install pandas==1.2.4` and in other `venv` you can use `pip install pandas==0.20.1`